# Installed nuget package depends on older version of System.Web.Mvc.dll after Publish

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, nuget

I have an MVC4 application developed with Visual Studio 2010.
Project works fine on IIS Express.
When publishing it to IIS8 and trying to access it I get an exception saying the `System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0` assembly could not be loaded.
The calling assembly is `AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc`, which is a NuGet package I use.

The way I understand it, my project referes to version 4.0.0.0 of `System.Web.Mvc`, while the package I'm using depends on 3.0.0.0.

1. If Visual Studio/IIS Express can run it perfectly, how come the published version has this problem?
2. I read a lot only today, but still couldn't figure it out.
   Is this what Binding Redirect used for?

I'm kind'a lost here, feeling like I don't really have any direction.
Any advice is welcomed.

Thanks in advance,
Shy.

Comment: Does VIsual Studio show any warning in the error list after building the solution? I have VS 13 and it shows me a warning when there are assembly version conflicts. Double-clicking the warning fixes the issue (adds the necessary binding redirects to the config file)

Comment: Yes, got the warning and clicked it already.
Unfortunately it didn't do the job.

Comment: Can you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16855426/1454888

Comment: My <configuration> doesn't have a xmlns property.
However, when entering the Add Reference window of VS, I see that only System.Web.Mvc 2.0.0.0 and 4.0.0.1 are installed.

Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: I don't know. Here is a post that talks about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406877/asp-net-mvc-security-patch-to-version-3-0-0-1-breaks-build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:**
I simply (Well it wasn't so simple) installed MVC3 in addition to versions 2 and 4.
Problem disappeared without the need of any further changes.

Solution:
Download and install MVC3 from [Microsoft's website](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4211).
In case installation failes:

1. Extract the setup file.
2. Open ParameterInfo.Xml in an editor.
3. Remove completely the `<Exe>` tag that refers to the vs10-kb2483190
   file.
4. Run setup again.

Thank you very much for your help @Augusto.

Hope this helps someone someday :)